# How to use line breaks in a slim variable?

Tags: ruby, slim-lang

I have this variable in **slim**:

```
- foo = 'my \n desired multiline <br/> string'
#{foo}
```

When I parse the output using the **slimrb command line command** the contents of the variable are encoded:

```
my \n desired multiline &lt;br/&gt; string
```

How can I have `slimrb` output the raw contents in order to generate multi-line strings?

*Note that neither `.html_safe` nor `.raw` are available.*

Comment: Do you mean `= foo`, not `#{foo}` ? The `#` will start a new tag.

Comment: @potashin double quotes cause the `\n` to be interpreted, but that has no effect, as in HTML new lines are ignored.

Comment: @matt The actual line says `td #{foo}`. Changing that to `td = foo` generates identical output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here. First in Ruby strings using single quotes – `'` – don’t convert `\n` to newlines, they remain as literal `\` and `n`. You need to use double quotes. This applies to Slim too.

Second, [Slim HTML escapes the result of interpolation by default](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Text_interpolation). To avoid this use double braces around the code. [Slim also HTML escapes Ruby output](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Output__) by default (using `=`). To avoid escaping in that case [use double equals (`==`)](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Output_without_HTML_escaping___).

Combining these two, your code will look something like:

```
- foo = "my \n desired multiline <br/> string"
td #{{foo}}
```

This produces:

```html
<td>my
 desired multiline <br/> string</td>
```

Comment: Both variants (`==` and `#{{}}`) work. Thanks a dozen, matt!

Answer (score 2):

An easier way is to use Line Indicators as verbatim texts `|` . Documentation [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Line_indicators) . For example;

```
p
 | This line is on the left margin.
   This line will have one space in front of it.
```